# Call objective-c methods class from Javascript using UIWebview?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

My requirement is: I need to initialize a specific objective-c class and call its method from javscript using UIWebview like below eg:

I have an objective-c class called "Calculator" which has the following methods

```
@interface Calculator : NSObject {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) start;
@property (nonatomic, retain) add:(NSInteger) a with:(NSInteger) b;
@property (nonatomic, retain) subract:(NSInteger) a by:(NSInteger) b;;

@end;
```

I have a UIWebview, in which I am loading HTML with JS. Here, I have a JS script function like

```
function callNativeClass() {

window.calc.start;

}
```

"calc" is the instance or namespace of the class. I need to call the start method from JS.

Can you please tell me, is there any option to call native objective-c class like PhoneGap?

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap does this. Download the framework from phonegap.com. You can create a custom plugin very easily to call the methods in Objective C file. Try this

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS